# asp.net Button replaces custom CSS CLASS

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

i am not sure what i am doing wrong but my asp.net button replaces the custom class i am setting in page.

## ASP.NET Page

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPrev" CssClass="btn prev" Text="Back"></asp:Button>
```

## Generated HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$PageContent$Competitions$ctl06$btnPrev" value="Back" id="PageContent_Competitions_ctl06_btnPrev" class="button">
```

How do i set custom class to button. please help.

## EDITS:

I checked it in BOTH: Chrome developer tools as well as VIEW SOURCE. both are showing above rendered HTML

Well, For time being i am going to use asp:LinkButton which does not overrides class attributes. I am now sure that something in my application which overrides the asp:Button class to "buttons" class.

thanks for pointing me to right direction. i will keep this question open until i figure out what is going on...

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on your ASP.NET control. And I'm pretty sure the generated HTML always includes the trailing slash (even though it's not required in HTML). When you put stuff into a SO question, make sure you copy it exactly from your code/markup - even a tiny typo can make a huge difference in the answer.

Comment: Have you checked you're not overwriting the CssClass. Example  *btnPrev.CssClass="button"*

Comment: As far as i know, while rendering asp.net preserves the class attribute. I feel there is a javascript which is looping through the buttons and adding the class

Comment: When you say "Generated HTML", are you pulling it from "View Source" or from your browser's developer tools? These will give you two totally different issues. The actual source will tell you what ASP.NET did. The dev tools tell you what's there now, which would mean it's javascript that's reassigning your class.

Comment: I am preety sure there is no javascript which loops through all the buttons and replaces the class with "button" class. I have more then 40 pages and only this pages seems to have this.

Comment: Try in fresh, empty page. You'll see it's working just fine. **Something** is overriding the class..

Comment: Are you sure this is the markup corresponding to your button? Normally asp.net outputs `type="button"` when you have an `asp:button` (unless you submitbehaior to submit). Is it possible that you have another button on the page which looks similar?

Comment: @Kenneth ASP.NET always makes it `type="submit"`, not `button`. These buttons are postback buttons by default.

Comment: What about server side code? I believe that @bastos.sergio was referring to reassigning `CssClass` in the code-behind and not Javascript.  Does your page inherit directly from `Page` or some custom `Page` base class?

Answer (score 2):

Since you say your actual source has this class, it must be bastos.sergio's comment or something similar, where some server code is overwriting your class. Aside from the `CssClass` property, you can also set it from `Attributes`, like:

```
btnPrev.Attributes.Remove("class");

btnPrev.Attributes["class"] = "button";
// or
btnPrev.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
```

I'd take a look for the words `CssClass` or `Attributes` in your code, and see if maybe it's being overwritten by mistake somewhere in there, possibly in a base class or other shared location.

If you can't track it down, try setting some breakpoints and watching the value of `btnPrev.CssClass` and `btnPrev.Attributes["class"]` at various points throughout the page lifecycle to see when the change happens.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
   $("#PageContent_Competitions_ctl06_btnPrev").removeClass("button");
   $("#PageContent_Competitions_ctl06_btnPrev").addClass("btn prev");
});
```